# Regex Pattern to negate a character

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a statement as below

```
#sv_q = " INSERT INTO alertuser.REALTIME
```

I'm trying to create a regex to match this line from a set of lines from the file, whenever insert keyword is used. But since a '#' is used at the beginning I wouldn't want to consider this line. How to achieve this. I tried the below regex, but still this line is getting considered, can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

```
static Pattern tracePattern = Pattern.compile("(?!\\#).*insert\\s*into",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher localMatcher = tracePattern.matcher(line); 
if (localMatcher.find()) { 
  //  doing some checks
}
```

Comment: Use the regex you have with `Matcher#matches()`.

Comment: Does it help? Please share your code.

Comment: static Pattern tracePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\#).*insert\\s*into",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher localMatcher = tracePattern.matcher((line));

if (localMatcher.find())
{ doing some checks}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `.find()`, you need to *anchor* the pattern at the beginning with `^` or `\A`. Besides, you'd better use word boundaries to only match whole words `insert` and `into`, and use `\s+` instead of `\s*` to enforce at least 1 occurrence of a whitespace between `insert` and `into`:

```
"^(?!#).*\\binsert\\s+into\\b"
```

You could shorten your solution to

```
if (s.matches("(?i)(?!#).*\\binsert\\s+into\\b.*")) { doing some checks}
```

The `matches()` method requires a full string match, and thus, you need to add the `.*` at the end. Also, the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` option can be used inline with the help of the embedded flag option `(?i)`. If your input can contain line breaks, use `(?si)` instead of `(?i)`.

Comment: When using this pattern, the records which are supposed to get selected is not getting selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"? Regex either matches a string or not.

Comment: Yes, the `String s = "#sv_q = \" INSERT INTO alertuser.REALTIME"` string should not be matched because there is a `#` at the beginning - just what you wrote. See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/6N16U7).

Comment: yep.. Thanks a lot :) btw can you please help me distinguish between find() and matches().